# How can I share data between views in rappidjs

Tags: javascript, url-routing

I build a menu view component with [rappidjs](http://www.rappidjs.com/) which has a list of entries in it. I also have some modules.

I want the module to register their menu entry. I thought building a Manager or a collection but this seems way to heave to me. Is there a simple way?

Implementation can be found here.

http://try.rappidjs.com/project/52b0d1e13bce060342000013

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the rappidjs.com website, it also uses a menu combined with the ModuleLoader.

In https://github.com/rappid/rappidjs.com/blob/master/public/app/Index.xml the menu is build with

```
<nav>
    <ui:ItemsView items="{pages}" tagName="ul" class="nav">
         <js:Template name="item">
               <li selected="{isPageSelected(item)}">
                     <a href="${item.link}">${item.label}</a>
               </li>
         </js:Template>
    </ui:ItemsView>
</nav>
```

See https://github.com/rappid/rappidjs.com/blob/master/public/app/IndexClass.js for the implementation of `isPageSelected`.

For a reusable solution, you could a menu component that gets the `ModuleLoader` 
 as attribute and dynamically get all registered modules from the `moduleLoader.$modules` array.

We haven't built such a component, because a menu can contain more items than the registered ones in the ModuleLoader.